# Create an object based on parameters from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm Using Rails 3.2 and i wish to know a " rails way " to create an object based on parameters coming from another. I have the class StoredItem and the class RequestedItem, they are not related, but during the process to attend the requested item i wish to list all itens and qty stored from a requested part number.
I thought something like

```
@requested_items = RequestedItem.includes(:item_description).where("item_request_id = ?", params[:id])

@stored_items = StoredItem.where("item_description_id = ?",@requested_items.item_description_id)
```

Obviously this seems don't work because i have a lot of descriptions id to compare, not only one, so, whats the best and correct way to make it work?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@stored_items = StoredItem.where("item_description_id IN (?)",@requested_items.map(&:item_description_id))
```

Or

```
@stored_items = StoredItem.where(:item_description_id => @requested_items.map(&:item_description_id))
```

Comment: The second option is much better (no pure SQL written which lets Rails deal with the SQL generation, following the DB Adapter). Also, `@requested_items.pluck(:item_description_id)` would be a little more efficient than a `.map(&:item_description_id)`

Comment: Good point, but depends if he's using requested items elsewhere

Comment: Great, i used the second option, it solved my question. Thanks Baloo and MrYoshiji ;)